# Non-degenerate sub $C^*$-algebra of the compact operators.

Tags: c-star-algebras, compact-operators

Let $B_0(H)$ be the compact operators on the Hilbert space $H$ and let $B \subseteq B_0(H)$ a $C^*$-subalgebra that acts non-degenerately on $H$. Let $\{p_i: i \in I\}$ be a maximal family of pairwise orthogonal minimal projections. The existence of this family is ensured by Zorn's lemma. Is it true that
$$H = \bigoplus_i p_i (H)$$

Attempt:

Write $K$ for the direct sum. If $K$ is a proper subspace, we may fix a non-zero $\xi \in K^\perp$. The idea is now to use this vector to construct a minimal projection that will contradict maximality, but I'm not sure how to use the non-degeneracy to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$
  p = \sum_{i\in I}p_i,
  $
where the sum is known to converge strongly.  Then, for every  $a$ in $B$, notice that
$$
  pa = \sum_{i\in I}p_ia,
  $$
where the convergence is now in norm since right-multiplication by compact operators turns strong convergence (of
bounded nets) into norm
convergence.  Therefore $pa\in B$.

Now, assuming by contraction that $p\neq 1$, and
since $B$ is non-degenenerate, there must be some element $a$ in $B$ such that $(1-p)a\neq 0$, and hence also that
$$
  c:= (1-p)aa^*(1-p) \neq 0.
  $$
Since $c$ is a self-adjoint compact operator in $B$, any one of its spectral projections,  say $q$,  also lie in $B$.
It is also clear that $q\perp p_i$ for every $i$, and since $q$ is necessarily finite dimensional, we may choose a
minimal projection among the projections of $B$ dominated by $q$.  The existence of  such a projection then contradicts
the maximality of the originaly chosen family.

Comment: "since multiplication by compact operators turns strong convergence into norm convergence" Can you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: If $\{x_i\}_i$ is a strongly converging net of bounded operators, with limit $x$,  and if $b$ is a compact operator, then $bx_i\to bx$ in norm.

Comment: I would expect that we at least need that $\{x_i\}$ is a norm-bounded net, because then you can easily approximate with finite rank operators.

Comment: Ok, I guess you indeed need to assume boundedness!

Comment: And this is satisfied in our case by orthogonality of the projections, I believe?

Comment: Yes, it is, since the net is formed by finite sums of the $p_i$, which have norm 1.

Comment: Indeed I think it is easier to prove that $x_ib\to xb$.  Perhaps I should edit to make the answer depend on this instead.

Comment: I am starting to doubt the statement in my second comment above in case the convergence of the $x_i$ is not in the $^*$-strong topology (which it is in my answer).

Comment: Do you think the answer contains a possible flaw?

Comment: My answer is now based on right multiplication by compacts so it is OK.  My doubt is just whether or not my comment above holds.

Comment: @user839372, please check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3935048/does-left-multiplication-by-compact-operators-turn-strong-convergence-into-norm